# Facebook connected but /me user is an empty object

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, undef

I used the example from the facebook documentation but after granting facebook permission to connect I cannot get any user info from the user object. The user is defined but all its attributes are null. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '161718123880158', // App ID
            channelUrl : '', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
            logging     : true
          });
          FB.api('/me', function(user) {
            if (user) {
              var image = document.getElementById('image');
              image.src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
              var name = document.getElementById('name');
              name.innerHTML = user.name
            }
          });
        };
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
         }(document));
      </script>
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="email,user_checkins">Login with Facebook</div>
      <div align="center">
        <img id="image"/>
        <div id="name"></div>
      </div>

    </body>
 </html>
```

The output is undef for name and empty image

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't got an active access token. If you do a put a console.log(user) and examine the response it shows the error.

1. What is the 'Website with Facebook login' field set to in your [app settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/161718123880158/summary)? It needs to match the URL that you are developing on.
2. Try wrapping the FB.api call in a FB.getLoginStatus callback function, like this:

   ```
   FB.getLoginStatus(function() {
      FB.api('/me', function(user) {
         //your code here
      });
    })
   ```

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. I'm not 100% sure which one fixed the issue. I updated the "Website with Facebook Login" to the exact url I was testing with but without adding FB.getLoginStatus in #2 it still does not work. Will the login work for all urls under the main domain? For example if we indicate "example.com" in the settings, will "example.com/mypage" work as well?